# Primefaces - menuBar - with Disabled Option

Tags: primefaces, menuitem, menubar

I am using primefaces 3.4 menuBar.

I am using menuItem as shown below.

```
<p:menuitem value="Click Here" 
                url="/faces/NewPage.xhtml"
                disabled="#{!user.isUserHasAccess}"/>
```

When user doesn't have access to the link it shows as grayed out. However user can still click on the link and it takes them to the url mentioned in the link.

I am after where user can still see the menuItem but can't click on it if they don't have access to them. The idea is so that they know what screens are available in the application and can request to the administrator if they need it.

Answer (score 0):

if "disabled=true" then only the component will disabled. In ur case value of "#{!user.isUserHasAccess}" may be "False"  check it..

Try with

```
<p:menuitem value="Click Here" url="/faces/NewPage.xhtml"
                disabled="#{user.isUserHasAccess}"/>
```

Comment: #{!user.isUserHasAccess} is correct. The bug is in primefaces 3.4 . This has been fixed in 3.4.2. Not it works.